# Get Facebook access token using PHP

Tags: php, facebook, token

I'm developing application which need access to user's facebook account. It is working, but I need to get user's facebook token and save it to MySQL database. How can I get facebook token using PHP (with permissions defined by me) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a good official guide/tutorial about just that in the facebook developers documentation.
What you're looking for is the [Server-Side authentication flow](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/server-side/), since it results with a long lived access token (60 days) which you can persist in your db and reuse when needed.

There's also the [Client-Side flow](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/client-side/) but that grants you short lived tokens (a few hours long) which are no good for persistancy.
If however you do decide to go with the client side flow then you can extend the expiration time of a **valid** token using the new endpoint which was introcuded due to the [deprecation of the offline_access permissions](http://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/).

Comment: Thanks for answer. I've used example code from your link (server side), but how can I get extended permissions ?

Comment: In that same guide, the first section "1. Redirect the user to the OAuth Dialog" has this *scope=COMMA_SEPARATED_LIST_OF_PERMISSION_NAMES* in the redirect url, add the needed permissions there.